# NUnit test execution fails because of timing and threading problems

Tags: c#, nunit, task-parallel-library, gitlab-ci, github-actions

We have a lot of test in our .NET application. Some of this tests are timing relevant and some code is multi threaded with the .NET TPL. Since several weeks we have a lot of problems with them. Before, the tests are running everytime successful.

I bring an example with a simple timer:

In the class [NotSoParallelOps](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Platform/blob/dev/src/Moryx.TestTools.UnitTest/NotSoParallelOps.cs#L107) Method ScheduleExecution (L107) a normal `System.Threading.Timer` will be started. The corresponding tests are in [NotSoParallelOpsTests](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Platform/blob/dev/src/Tests/Moryx.Tests/Threading/NotSoParallelOpsTests.cs#L79) Method ScheduleExecutionWithStop (L79) where the timer will be started, the test thread is blocked for some time and then it will be evaluated if the timer elapsed.

Another example with the TPL:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public void Start(int delay)
    {
        Task.Run(async delegate
        {
            await Task.Delay(delay);
            TaskDone?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        });
    }

    public event EventHandler TaskDone;
}

[TestFixture]
public class FooTests
{
    [Test]
    public void TestRunner()
    {
        // Arrange
        var foo = new Foo();
        var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        foo.TaskDone += delegate
        {
            resetEvent.Set();
        };

        // Act
        foo.Start(1000);
        var result = resetEvent.WaitOne(2000);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(result, "Task not done in time");
    }
}
```

A new task will be started with `Task.Run`. The task is delayed for some reasons and then an event is raised. The test registeres to the event and checks if the task is executed in time.

If the tests are executed with `Visual Studio Resharper UnitTest Explorer` which is using the NUnit test runner, the tests are mostly successful. If the nunit-console will be used, the tests are [failing very often](https://github.com/dbeuchler/MORYX-Platform/runs/1121903460?check_suite_focus=true) but also [succeed sometimes](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Platform/runs/1113831088?check_suite_focus=true). The same is not only on local machines, also on GitHub Workflow runners and GitLab CI runners. Same problems, same results.

An idea was to change the time how long is waited for the timer test. It works but why to do this now? The tests were successfull for several month/years. Also the build infrastructure was getting faster and more performant.

I applied the same idea to the `Task.Run` test. But it does not run even if I set the time to 60 seconds. The most confusing on this is that the test are working fine on my local machine but not on GitHub Workflow runners and GitLab CI runners.

Does anyone have an idea what I can do to fix this or is there any better idea to tests such lines of code?

- NUnit Console: 3.11.1
- NUnit TestAdapter: 3.17.0

Comment: Instead of an event, have you tried using [TaskCompletionSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: From outside I do not know that Task.Run is used within Foo. Sure Start can return a task and I could use TCS but this is just a sample what I have extracted from our code.

Comment: Oh, black box of surprises ... ok. Tricky ... But asked differently: Do you really need this to fail at tMax? Or do you just want to make sure to hit a certain benchmark on a certain environment but allowing for "spikes"?

Comment: For the timer, the spikes in general are okay but why do they vary so much? in the  sample with Task.Run, I can set the time of the WaitOne to hours, it will not be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give it a try to rewrite your test to use `TaskCompletionSource` with `CancellationToken`.

If you don't need the `EventArgs` then the rewritten version of the test would look like this:

```cs
[Test]
public async Task TestRunner()
{
    // Arrange
    var foo = new Foo();
    var fooTaskCompleted = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    var timeoutPolicy = new CancellationTokenSource(2000);
    timeoutPolicy.Token.Register((future) => ((TaskCompletionSource<object>)future).TrySetCanceled(), useSynchronizationContext: false, state: fooTaskCompleted);

    foo.TaskDone += delegate
    {
        fooTaskCompleted.SetResult(null);
    };

    // Act
    foo.Start(1000);
    await fooTaskCompleted.Task;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsFalse(fooTaskCompleted.Task.IsCanceled);
    Assert.IsFalse(fooTaskCompleted.Task.IsFaulted);
}
```

If you need the `EventArgs` then you could rewrite the `TestRunner` method like this:

```cs
[Test]
public async Task TestRunner()
{
    // Arrange
    var foo = new Foo();
    var fooTaskCompleted = new TaskCompletionSource<EventArgs>();
    var timeoutPolicy = new CancellationTokenSource(2000);
    timeoutPolicy.Token.Register((future) => ((TaskCompletionSource<EventArgs>)future).TrySetCanceled(), useSynchronizationContext: false, state: fooTaskCompleted);

    foo.TaskDone += (s, e) =>
    {
        fooTaskCompleted.TrySetResult(e);
    };

    // Act
    foo.Start(1000);
    var eventArgs = await fooTaskCompleted.Task;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsFalse(fooTaskCompleted.Task.IsCanceled);
    Assert.IsFalse(fooTaskCompleted.Task.IsFaulted);
}
```

Comment: A bit more complicated but I will try this for the Task.Run case! Thanks - I will give you a hint if it was successful or not!

Comment: Hi @dennis, is there any progress?

Comment: Yes, the work arround with the TaskCompletionSource works. For the rest, i did not really know a resolution. In some of my other projects, the tests are working with a newer version of the Nunit Console runner.